# importing BTC historical data into spreadsheet

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to import a column with all the closing BTC price into a Google sheet. (within a specific set of dates)
I already have this script that allows importJSON:

```
/**
* Imports JSON data to your spreadsheet Ex: IMPORTJSON("http://myapisite.com","city/population")
* @param url URL of your JSON data as string
* @param xpath simplified xpath as string
* @customfunction
*/
function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){ 
  try{
    // /rates/EUR
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    var content = res.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var patharray = xpath.split(".");
    //Logger.log(patharray);
    for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
      json = json[patharray[i]];
    }
    //Logger.log(typeof(json));
    if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
      return "Node Not Available";
    } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
      var tempArr = [];  
      for(var obj in json){
        tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
      }
      return tempArr;
    } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
      return json;
    }
  }
  catch(err){
      return "Error getting data";  
  }
  
}
```

in which I am able to get for i.e. the last price with this JSON call:

```
=importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/marketsvs_currency=eur&ids=bitcoin","0.current_price")
```

anyways I'm not able to make a correct JSON call or something similar to import a column with the btc closing price from a whatever date to current date.
I have installed a spreadsheet extension called cryptosheet and tried to use the SS() function but nothing works so far.

Comment: Can you provide the detail of `nothing works so far`? For example, if an error occurs, please show it.

Comment: for example on the coinjecko api documentation this is the call for a coin price history: ''' https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=30-12-2017&localization=false ''' so i type ''' =importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=30-12-2017&localization=false") '''  and it says ''' error getting data '''

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and question, I proposed a modified formula as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

From your replying and your question, I could understand like below.

- You want to retrieve the values of `current_price` using your script.
- The URL is `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=30-12-2017&localization=false`.

#### Modification points:

- From your replying, it seems that the xpath is not used. By this, I think that the error occurs.
- When I saw the data from the URL and your script, the formula might be as follows.

#### Modified formula:

```
=IMPORTJSON(A1, "market_data.current_price")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/history?date=30-12-2017&localization=false` is put to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your replying since its more clear how to use JSON format i still can't do what i want: i want a column with all the closing price of btc in a given time range; according to coinjeko docs this is the JSON location of the data set: ''' https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=10 ''' and indeed if i go on that link there are all the clonsing price of btc in the previous 10 days. Now if i try to put that link in the cell A1 and type in the cell A2: ''' =IMPORTJSON(A1, "prices") ''' it only gives me a column with a sequence from 0 to 240

Comment: @federico Thank you for replying. At first, can I ask you whether my answer resolved your question? Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand whether my answer resolved your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: It is possible to get multiple coins' historical data with 1 API call?